# How can I calculate Actual Size of TextEffect?

Tags: c#, wpf

I made a customcontrol inherit from TextBlock for LetterSpacing, here are my codes:

```
public class NewTextBlock : TextBlock
    {                  
        public NewTextBlock() : base() {                        
            var dp = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(
                TextBlock.TextProperty,
                typeof(TextBlock));
            dp.AddValueChanged(this, (sender, args) =>
            {
                LetterSpacingChanged(this);
            });            
        }
        static void LetterSpacingChanged(DependencyObject d)
        {
            NewTextBlock TB = d as NewTextBlock;
            TB.TextEffects.Clear();
            for (int i = 1; i <= TB.Text.Length; i++)
            {                
                TranslateTransform transform = new TranslateTransform(TB.LetterSpacing, 0);
                TextEffect effect = new TextEffect();
                effect.Transform = transform;
                effect.PositionStart = i;
                effect.PositionCount = TB.Text.Length;                
                TB.TextEffects.Add(effect);
                if (effect.CanFreeze)
                {
                    effect.Freeze();
                }
            }           
        }
        public double LetterSpacing
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(LetterSpacingProperty); }
            set { SetValue(LetterSpacingProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for LetterSpacing.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty LetterSpacingProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("LetterSpacing", typeof(double), typeof(NewTextBlock), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0, new PropertyChangedCallback(LetterSpacingChanged)));

        private static void LetterSpacingChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            LetterSpacingChanged(d);
        }        
    }
```

Now when I use it like this:

```
<Test:NewTextBlock Background="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" LetterSpacing="5" Text="123123123123">
            <Test:NewTextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="45"></RotateTransform>
            </Test:NewTextBlock.LayoutTransform>
        </Test:NewTextBlock>
```

It turns out to be like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EF18Y.png)

As the red background showed, it looks like the actual width of the NewTextBlock does not include the width of the TextEffect.

I want to find a way to get the actual width of the TextEffect and set a right actual width to the NewTextBlock.

How can I do this?

Comment: Don't use the PropertyDiscriptor to register a property changed callback. If you are not careful it will create a severe per instance memory leak. Better override the the dependency property in a static constructor. For example: `static NewTextBlock() => TextProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(NewTextBlock), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(string), OnTextChanged));`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `DependencyPropertyDescriptor` to register a property changed callback. If you are not careful (which is the case with your code) it will create a (potentially severe) per instance memory leak.
Better override the the dependency property's metadata in a `static` constructor to register a new callback (see example below).

`TextBlock` does not support custom character spacing. `TextBlock` completely relies on the provided font (or typeface) to calculate the actual text width. Since `MeasureOverride` is sealed, you must force the new `Width` after a change of the `Text` value or any text related property change in general (for example `FontSize` etc.).
This means, to implement the sizing behavior correctly you would have to override the property metadata for all relevant properties to trigger the recalculations of the actual `NewTextBlock` width. You can follow the metadata override for the `TextBlock.TextProperty` property of the below example.

To calculate the width of a formatted string you usually use the `FormattedText` class (see below). In your case, you would have to include the current character spacing into the computation.

```cs
public class NewTextBlock : TextBlock
{
  public double LetterSpacing
  {
    get => (double)GetValue(LetterSpacingProperty);
    set => SetValue(LetterSpacingProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty LetterSpacingProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "LetterSpacing", 
    typeof(double), 
    typeof(NewTextBlock), 
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(double), OnLetterSpacingChanged));

  static NewTextBlock() 
  {
    TextProperty.OverrideMetadata(
      typeof(NewTextBlock), 
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(string), OnTextChanged));
  }

  public NewTextBlock() 
  {
    this.TextEffects = new TextEffectCollection();
  }

  private static void OnTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    => (d as NewTextBlock).ApplyTextEffects();

  private static void OnLetterSpacingChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) 
    => (d as NewTextBlock).ApplyTextEffects();

  private void ApplyTextEffects()
  {
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Text))
    {
      return;
    }

    this.TextEffects.Clear();
    for (int characterIndex = 1; characterIndex <= this.Text.Length; characterIndex++)
    {
      var transform = new TranslateTransform(this.LetterSpacing, 0);
      var effect = new TextEffect
      {
        Transform = transform,
        PositionStart = characterIndex,
        PositionCount = this.Text.Length
      };

      this.TextEffects.Add(effect);
      if (effect.CanFreeze)
      {
        effect.Freeze();
      }
    }

    AdjustCurrentWidth();
  }

  private void AdjustCurrentWidth()
  {
    var typeface = new Typeface(this.FontFamily, this.FontStyle, this.FontWeight, this.FontStretch);
    double pixelsPerDip = VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(this).PixelsPerDip;
    var formattedText = new FormattedText(this.Text, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight, typeface, this.FontSize, this.Foreground, pixelsPerDip);
    double totalLetterSpacingWidth = (this.Text.Length - 1) * this.LetterSpacing;
    double totalTextWidth = formattedText.WidthIncludingTrailingWhitespace + totalLetterSpacingWidth;

    this.Width = totalTextWidth;
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems I can achieve what I need by drawing a FormattedText directly without TextEffect..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I missed the point in this STextBlock but it looks to me like you could (maybe should) just use the Glyphs frameworkelement instead.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/introduction-to-the-glyphrun-object-and-glyphs-element?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.glyphs?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

EG

```
<!-- "Hello World!" with explicit character widths for proportional font -->
<Glyphs 
   FontUri             = "C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\ARIAL.TTF"
   FontRenderingEmSize = "36"
   UnicodeString       = "Hello World!"
   Indices             = ",80;,80;,80;,80;,80;,80;,80;,80;,80;,80;,80"
   Fill                = "Maroon"
   OriginX             = "50"
   OriginY             = "225"
/>

<!-- "Hello World!" with fixed-width font -->
<Glyphs 
   FontUri             = "C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\COUR.TTF"
   FontRenderingEmSize = "36"
   StyleSimulations    = "BoldSimulation"
   UnicodeString       = "Hello World!"
   Fill                = "Maroon"
   OriginX             = "50"
   OriginY             = "300"
/>
```

Comment: I am sorry about that; I have just fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution from the code of @BionicCode

```
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
        {
            base.OnRender(drawingContext);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text))
            {                
                double PositionX = Padding.Left;
                double PositionY = Padding.Top;
                foreach (var i in Text)
                {
                    var FT = new FormattedText(i.ToString(), CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight, new Typeface(FontFamily,FontStyle,FontWeight,FontStretch), FontSize, Foreground);                    
                    drawingContext.DrawText(FT, new Point(PositionX, PositionY));
                    PositionX += FT.Width+LetterSpacing;
                    var t = Width;                    
                }
            }
        }
```